# azureml mlflow.projects.run raises AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'conda_env_path'

Tags: mlflow, azureml-python-sdk

I've tried running the code on this page through pycharm on my local machine and connecting an an azureml compute cluster.
[azureml mlflow projects (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-mlflow-projects?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli)

I have my MLProject file:

```
name: mlflow_test
conda_env: conda.yaml
entry_points:
  testing:
    command: "python mlflow_test.py"
```

Set up connection to the workspace, set the tracking uri to be the workspace tracking uri and then run:

```py
    mlflow.projects.run('.',
                    entry_point='testing',
                    experiment_name='mlflow_test',
                    backend='azureml',
                    backend_config={"COMPUTE": "general-compute", "USE_CONDA": True}
                    )
```

general compute is the name of a compute cluster I have created.

This always raises the error:
AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'conda_env_path'

looking at the azureml-mlflow code it seems to be looking for mlproject.conda_env_path where mlproject is a mlflow Project class that doesn't have any attribute conda_env_path, infact conda_env_path is passed into the constructor and becomes Project().env_config_path.

Have I done something completely wrong here, if so, many thanks in advance

I have tried not using a conda envrionment, azureml seems to require the environment specified to be a conda environment for remote compute.

I've tried USE_CONDA True and False but according to documentation, if COMPUTE is specified this has no effect.

I tried changing the azureml-mlflow code to reference env_config_path and this raised another error all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the scenario, I have reproduced the issue with [sample notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/track-and-monitor-experiments/using-mlflow/train-projects-remote/train-projects-remote.ipynb)
[image]
It seems like the latest `mlflow` package has dropped the support for MLproject for remote compute. You can execute the code snippet in `local` without `backend_config`.

To solve the issue, downgrade the `mlflow` version to 1.25.0.

```
pip install mlflow==1.25.0
```

With the below package versions:
[image]

The run successfully executed.
[image]

As mentioned in the shared [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-mlflow-projects?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli)

`Support for MLflow Projects in Azure Machine Learning will end on September 30, 2023.`

To use the latest packages please refer to [Azure Machine Learning Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-cli-runs?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=interactive,cli) as per recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. weird that that shared documentation is the one I was working off. Can see it's been editted recently, maybe they've just added that warning in. Thanks for testing it all out and confirming it works with 1.25.